# How to create an XSD schema file from an XML file?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to create an XSD schema file from an existing XML file but am getting errors.  Currently I am trying to use the XSD command prompt tool to generate the XSD file.  Any advice on mistakes with my XML file?  Or any other tools I should try instead?  Here is my XML file:

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly'>
        <s:AttributeType name="c0" rs:name="FIRST_NAME" rs:number="1" rs:nullable="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="30"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="c1" rs:name="MIDDLE_NAME" rs:number="2" rs:nullable="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="30"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="c2" rs:name="LAST_NAME" rs:number="3">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="60" rs:maybenull="false"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="c3" rs:name="OTHER_ID" rs:number="4" rs:nullable="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="24"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="c4" rs:name="FS_LUN_CODE_ID" rs:number="5" rs:nullable="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="2"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="c5" rs:name="FS_NAME_ID_PAYOR" rs:number="6" rs:nullable="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="c6" rs:name="FS_TRAN_TIME" rs:number="7" rs:nullable="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="c7" rs:name="NAME_ID" rs:number="8">
            <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="c8" rs:name="FS_TRAN_DATE" rs:number="9" rs:nullable="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="date" dt:maxLength="6" rs:fixedlength="true"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row c0='SHELLI' c1='A' c2='AANENSON' c3='671590' c4='N' c5='0' c6='32885' c7='12' c8='2007-09-11'/>
    <z:row c0='SHELLI' c1='A' c2='AANENSON' c3='671590' c4='N' c5='0' c6='32885' c7='12' c8='2007-09-11'/>
    <z:row c0='SHELLI' c1='A' c2='AANENSON' c3='671590' c4='N' c5='0' c6='32885' c7='12' c8='2007-09-11'/>
    <z:row c0='SHELLI' c1='A' c2='AANENSON' c3='671590' c4='N' c5='0' c6='32885' c7='12' c8='2007-09-11'/>
    <z:row c0='WILLIAM' c1='' c2='AASEN' c3='916031' c4='N' c5='0' c6='55833' c7='13' c8='2007-07-27'/>
    <z:row c0='WILLIAM' c1='' c2='AASEN' c3='916031' c4='N' c5='0' c6='55833' c7='13' c8='2007-07-27'/>
    <z:row c0='WILLIAM' c1='' c2='AASEN' c3='916031' c4='N' c5='0' c6='55833' c7='13' c8='2007-07-27'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way to accomplish this would be to download the 30 day trial of [Altova XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/download/xmlspy/xml_editor_enterprise.html).  It has a very nice XML to XSD feature that you can customize completely.

Comment: Thank you, Spy is a very helpful software.  But it generated more than one XSD file from the above XML file.  I only want one XSD file cause I want to use this to create an SSIS package.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that an XSDL schema document can only describe one namespace. Your XML document makes use of multiple namespaces, so you need to have a XSD file for each namespace (i.e. dt.xsd, rs.xsd z.xsd etc.)

Not familiar with SSIS, but I would assume that if it supports multiple XML namespaces and can validate each namespace against a schema, that it should support an XSD per namespace.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a document defined by [NOTE-XML-Data](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/NOTE-XML-data-0105/), an W3C Note (not a Rec), rather than an XML Schema Document. Does your tool have options for the type of document output?

Comment: I don't understand your question, Jon.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: By XSD I normally understand an XMLSchema Document, as described at http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema. This doesn't look like one. It doesn't have the XMLSchema namespace or use any of it's elements. This is an XML Data document, very different.